# How can i select one value from a multidimentional list

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python trying out something with some friends and couldn't figure out how to select a single value from this list

```
pokemon_options = [[0, "squirtle", 44, 48, 65, 43], 
[1, "charmander", 39, 52, 43 ], 
[2, "bulbasaur", 45, 49, 49, 45]]
```

Comment: `pokemon_options[0][1]` to select second item of first list. Change indexes accordingly to get the value you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select a single value, you would need to use double indexes. For example, to access "squirtle" you would use `pokemon_options[0][1]` because it is in the 1st row (0) and second column (1)